# How to get rid of the absolute value when solving a system of complex equations?

Tags: complex-analysis, systems-of-equations, matlab, absolute-value

I'm trying to solve a system of complex equations, but I don't know how to deal with the absolute value (magnitude of the complex number). I had the idea of squaring both sides to make it go away, but I wasn't sure if this is valid (aside from making it more complicated). What's the right way to approach solving equations with absolute value in them such as the following system

$$
\frac{G}{|(0.1253-i0.9921)r^2-(1.3602-i0.8044)r+1|} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

and the second equation is
$$
\frac{G}{|(0.3681-i0.9298)r^2-(1.3681-i0.9298)r+1|} = 1
$$

Comment: Squaring is fine.  It doesn't make the modulus "go away", but rather $|z|^2 = z\overline{z}.$

Comment: Is there another way? By-hand calculations become more complicated.

Comment: Also, if I were to use MATLAB to solve them, do I just use the abs() function in MATLAB?